# PyPDF2 pdf text to json - issue with \n in json dump

Tags: python, json, pdf

I've made a script that uses PyPDF2 to read text from PDF documents and export to a json file. The dumped json file has a lot of these new line additions (\n) which will make reading the json file difficult at the next stage.

Here is an example of the output:

```
{
    "company": "Poly",
    "doctype": "Sustainability_Report",
    "year": "2021",
    "text": "1/30Poly \n—\nSustainability report \n20202/30 Sustainability report 2020\n—\nIntroduction\nAbout Poly 3\nOur approach to sustainability 3\nStakeholder dialogue and materiality assessment  4 \nClimate neutrality  6\nCircularity  12\nTransparency  15\nInclusion  20\nGRI Content Index  25\nIn this detailed sustainability report, Poly’s first, you will be able to explore the \ndetails of our sustainability strategy, management and progress. The report has been \nprepared in accordance with GRI Stan
```

The \n appears all the way through the resulting document - does anyone know why this is happening and if there is a good solution without adding a replace?

Comment: Hi @KJ thanks for the reply - can you recommend a good way to get rid of it in the json dump?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want newline characters, you can just replace them with spaces:

```py
>>> "a\nb\nc".replace("\n", " ")
'a b c'
```